# Swift, multiple inheritance from classes

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift, compiler-errors

Here is my custom class that I have created:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol vaBeanDelegate
{

}

class vaBean: CBCentralManager, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

override init!(delegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate!, queue: dispatch_queue_t!) {
    println("bean initialised")
    super.init()
    self.delegate = delegate
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    println("discovered peripheral(s)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state) {
    case .PoweredOff:
        println("hardware is powered off")

    case .PoweredOn:
        println("hardware is powered on and ready")
        //centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    case .Resetting:
        println("hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        println("state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        println("state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        println("hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
    println("didConnectPeripheral")
}
}
```

I just don't know how to initialize it from my main ViewController. When I try the following it complains that ViewController does not conform to the CBCentralManagerDelegate:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myBean: vaBean!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("blueToothTest v1.00")
    println("opening bluetooth connection ...")
    myBean = vaBean(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
}
```

Comment: It's because you can't have multiple inheritance in Swift. You can have as many protocols as you want but only one superclass.

Comment: When you write `vaBean(delegate: self, queue: nil)`, the `self` refers to the ViewController, which cannot serve as a delegate because it doesn't conform to the delegate protocol. I think your best bet is to change your custom initializer to take only the `queue` parameter, and have it set `self.delegate = self` -- in the context of the initializer, `self` will refer to your vaBean instance, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Todd, appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Swift and Objective-C are single inheritance only, you can't have more than one superclass for a class.

When you see Swift code with what looks like multiple superclasses in their declaration, you'll see that at most, one of the names in the declaration is a superclass, the others are names of protocols.

In Objective-C the these would have been written with `<angled brackets>` but this is not the case for Swift.

Comment: the others are names of _protocols_

Comment: @BryanChen or **interfaces** in Java

Answer (score 2):

Swift doesn't support multiple inheritance. But your ViewController doesn't need to inherit from vaBeanDelegate if you merely want to *access* it, as your question suggests.

Comment: You'd need to show more code (especially the signature for the initializer for `vaBean` that you're callling). What's required of a `vaBean delegate`?

Comment: I'm trying to do something very simple, but struggling. I want a separate file (class) that is simply an inheritance of CBCentralManager - so that it can handle bluetooth. I had the code working in the main ViewController, but wanted to move it out so that I could follow the MVC ethic.

Answer (score 1):

**Your ViewController is not conforming to the protocol *CBCentralManagerDelegate***

Looking at this:

```
myBean = vaBean(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

The first argument of the constructor *init* expects an object for the parameter *delegate* that conforms to the protocol *CBCentralManagerDelegate*. You pass *self* there, which is your view controller, which does not implement that delegate (even though it does not define any functions yet. That will throw you the error.

You have 2 choices here to solve this:

1) Implement *CBCentralManagerDelegate* directly in your view controller by declaring it this way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate { 
    // Here goes the rest of your class
    // Don't forget to add delegate functions once you added some
}
```

2) Add an extension to the class at the end of your file that adds conformance for the protocol

```
extension UIViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate { 
    // Empty for now since the protocol does not require anything at the moment
    // Don't forget to add delegate functions once you added some
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it complains that ViewController does not conform to the CBCentralManagerDelegate, you can try to use below code.

```
extension viewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    //implement the methods in CBCentralManagerDelegate here
}
```

In swift that is single inheritance only as Abizern said above, but that support implements multiple Protocols, like Interface in Java.

In your sample code, vaBean implement protocol CBCentralManagerDelegate.